# Disable Email Sent to Administrators from addError()

Tags: exception, adderror

I created an addError() method in a trigger with a custom error message like so:

```
item.addError('Hey! You aren't authorized to do that!');
```

I have also received error emails like so:

> Dear Admin,
> Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization...(etc)
> FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Hey! You aren't authorized to do that!: []

I suppose I have two questions:

1. **Am I getting this email because of the `addError()` message?** I looked [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) and didn't see it mention anything about getting an email, but because it has the same message I have to assume it is correleated.
2. **If it is because of that `addError()` message, is there a way to turn the email off?**

Comment: the error message says occurring in a trigger but you state you coded in a controller

Comment: Sorry, I meant trigger. I will edit that now.

Comment: in what context is the trigger invoked -- standard user interface, some VF controller, some REST class, etc?

Comment: Normally, the trigger is invoked from saving a record on a VF page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, addError doesn't send emails. You have code that does something with "allOrNone" set to true, without a try-catch block, and so it's failing.

The "Last Modified By" user is the one that receives exceptions for a given unit of code, and there's no way to disable that.

Start catching your exceptions, and you'll stop getting the emails.

Comment: Yep. It was a not-often used controller that I didn't think to look at. No try-catch. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Using a VF controller, and doing DML, you need the following syntax to avoid the email

```
   public PageReference mySave() {
      try {
        update theRecord;
      }
      catch (DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()):
     }
   }
```

The standard UI will catch DML errors, as will Data Loader - but custom Visualforce DML will not

Answer (score 0):

You have to throw error, it will stop execution of further code. You will got mail by this approach.